# c# How to permanently stretch the column line to the last long text in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Whenever I open my system the datagridview column line would always cover the rest of the text in a row, so i have to manually adjust it everytime. How do i anchor the column line to the last long text permanently?

Comment: If I find it hard to understand the situation you're describing. A screenshot might help?

Comment: Also: winforms? Asp.net?

Comment: I agree with Leon, your comment:... _”the datagridview column line would always cover the rest of the text in a row”_ … what does this mean? What is a “datagridview column line”? Your description is not clear. I am having a hard time visualizing what a “column line” is. A screen shot would be helpful and possibly “point” to the column line that is covering the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to resize all the columns to fit the length of the cell content :

```
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```